# Shortcut for toggling line numbers in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to setup a shortcut in 2012 (via a toolbar button or keyboard shortcut) for toggling line numbers. I prefer to have them off most of the time and it's nice to turn them on quickly for working with another developer without going through the menus.

For 2010 there are questions like this but they tell you to use macros and 2012 does not have macros in favor of add-ins.

Can someone tell me the best way in 2012 to accomplish this?

Comment: @Orchi, It says right in my question that it doesn't work the same way in 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2012 you can use add-ins to map all macro functionality, and hook it up to toolbars and keyboard shortcuts.

I persisted the solution as a GitHub repository in order to document how to map pre-2012 macros to 2012 add-in commands, from creation to completion.  Long story short, look up the macro definition you want in Visual Studio 2010, then create an add-in command in Visual Studio 2012 (Extensibility project type) that maps that functionality (modify 3 methods to create command) and deploy (copy 2 built files) and map keyboard shortcuts.

As it is checked in, it fulfills your particular request for line number toggling in files and works slickly with keyboard shortcuts.

Please check out **https://github.com/dherod/MacroMapper.git**
The README.md file shows all the details about how to extend, or just install and use to solve your request.  Basically you just need to close all VS 2012 instances, and copy the 2 files in the MacroMapper\INSTALL dir to your VS 2012 installation location \Addins dir, then map keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a helpful extension to manage your visual studio shortcuts which is also lists the line toggling shortcuts

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2964c90-68e2-4ddd-861a-bd66e5cd4434